# How could I send a curl output straight to an Azure Storage?

Tags: node.js, bash, azure, curl

I'm trying to send downloaded files using bash using a curl request:

```
    
for secao in $tipo_dou;
do
    download="curl -k --silent -fL -b cookies.iakim 'https://inlabs.in.gov.br/index.php?p=$ano-$mes-$dia&dl=$ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.zip' -H 'origem: 736372697074' -o


    " 
    echo $download > $ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.sh
    sh $ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.sh
    rm -rf $ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.sh
done
```

By doing that I was able to retrieve the data into my local machine.

The problem is: I must retrieve that data and send it towards an Azure Storage and for that I've been trying to make a pipe such this ex:

```
  filename=$ano-$mes-$dia&dl=$ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.zip
for secao in $tipo_dou;
do
    download="curl -k --silent -fL -b cookies.iakim 'https://inlabs.in.gov.br/index.php?p=$ano-$mes-$dia&dl=$ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.zip' -H 'origem: 736372697074' 
                 |
                curl -X PUT -T - -H x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob 'https://server.blob.core.windows.net/ape/filename?st=2023-01-25T18:41:00Z&se=2025-12-01T02:41:00Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=SIGNATUREID'


    " 
    echo $download > $ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.sh
    sh $ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.sh
    rm -rf $ano-$mes-$dia-$secao.sh
done
```

And so far I was only able to login into the system that I'm trying to download it but I got an error like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:6b17fae3-601e-0065-5483-31ec49000000
Time:2023-01-26T12:43:31.1912380Z</Message>
```

And to execute that script I'm using Node:

```
 const { exec } = require('child_process');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const zlib = require('zlib');
 
 const directoryFiles = fs.readdirSync('.');


 const download = exec('sh xml-downloader.sh', (error, stdout, stderr ) => {
     console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ', stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ', error);
        }
 })
```

Is there any other way that I could do that?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks like an issue with your SAS URL (`https://server.blob.core.windows.net/ape/filename?st=2023-01-25T18:41:00Z&se=2025-12-01T02:41:00Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=SIGNATUREID`). It is missing the permissions. There should be `sp` parameter in your SAS URL.

Comment: The lack of quoting is jarring. Your code is very brittle and will not work if one of the variables contains whitespace or a shell wildcard character which happens to match some files. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: I've tried that tho.

```
><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was racwdl
```

https://cncdevrseus2container01.blob.core.windows.net/ape?sp=racwdl&st=2023-01-25T18:41:00Z&se=2025-12-01T02:41:00Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=SIGNATUREID

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your reply. I read the exemple you gave and made few adjustments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FabioFaria - Your 2nd URL is missing the blob name. It should be something like `https://cncdevrseus2container01.blob.core.windows.net/ape/filename?sp=racwdl&st=2023-01-25T18:41:00Z&se=2025-12-01T02:41:00Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=SIGNATUREID`.

Comment: @GauravMantri I checked that already but now I'm facing an issue because I'm sending a zip file and it's not allowed apparently. Since I'm getting a 501 For not supported encoding type like gzip. :/

Appreciate tho!

Answer (score 1):

@FabioFaria as mentioned, you'll need to [configure a SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#authenticate-to-azure-and-authorize-access-to-blob-data) to enable your app to access blob storage.

Alternatively, since you're already using node to run the application, you could create an app registration for your node application and [use the blob client directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#code-examples).